# “possible duplicate of…” is uncapitalised

Tags: bug, design, comments, duplicates

When we close-vote a question as a duplicate of another question, a comment is auto-generated. This comment reads:

> possible duplicate of [Title of Dupe Question]

For as long as I've been here, that's been driving me bonkers every time I see it.

Can we *please* have a properly capitalised “Possible” here? Pretty please?

(I know, I know. It's a tiny detail. But *such an annoying one*!)

Comment: Also see [this question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/as-a-site-about-elu-should-we-maintain-correct-grammar-punctuation-etc-thro), where the request was quietly granted a few months back.